# passing variables values to paypal API - first_name and last_name

Tags: javascript, json, api, paypal

I've stored the first_name and last_name from a previous forms on my website.

When I open the popup form the PAYPAL API, the first name is filled correctly, but the second one it's not.

this is my code:

payment: function (data, actions) {

```
        var retrievePersonalInfo = localStorage.getItem('personalInfoData');

        var data = JSON.parse(retrievePersonalInfo);

        var first_name = data[0];
        var last_name = data[1];

        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [{
                        amount: {
                            total: '0.01',
                            currency: 'EUR'
                        },
                        item_list: {
                            shipping_address:
                                    {
                                        recipient_name: first_name,
                                        last_name: last_name,
                                        line1: "line1",
                                        line2: "line2",
                                        city: "PT",
                                        country_code: "PT",
                                        postal_code: "shipToZip",
                                        phone: "011862212345678",
                                        state: "shipToState",
                                    }
                        }
                    }]
            },

            /*experience: {
             input_fields: {
             no_shipping: 1,
             address_override: 1
             }
             }*/
        });
    },
```

the result is a full error page in the console because it's not accepting my "last_name";

--
When I erase the last_name the code works perfectly but the result it's this:

var fullname = data[0];
            var l_fullname = data[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgqNA.png);

```
        return actions.payment.create({
            payment: {
                transactions: [{
                        amount: {
                            total: '0.01',
                            currency: 'EUR'
                        },
                        item_list: {
                            shipping_address:
                                    {
                                        recipient_name: fullname + l_fullname,
                                        line1: "line1",
                                        line2: "line2",
                                        city: "PT",
                                        country_code: "PT",
                                        postal_code: "shipToZip",
                                        phone: "011862212345678",
                                        state: "shipToState",
                                    }
                        }
                    }]
            },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `recipient_name` field is split by a space when pre-filling the form. In your second example there's no space.

```
shipping_address: {
    recipient_name: fullname + ' ' + l_fullname,
    line1: "line1",
    line2: "line2",
    city: "PT",
    country_code: "PT",
    postal_code: "shipToZip",
    phone: "011862212345678",
    state: "shipToState",
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much mate!